# How to cache using apollo-server

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

The apollo basic example at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources.html#Implementing-your-own-cache-backend they state that doing a redis cache is as simple as:

```
const { RedisCache } = require('apollo-server-cache-redis');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  cache: new RedisCache({
    host: 'redis-server',
    // Options are passed through to the Redis client
  }),
  dataSources: () => ({
    moviesAPI: new MoviesAPI(),
  }),
});
```

When I look at the examples of non-redis, it states that it's a simple `{ get, set }` for cache. This means I should theoretically be able to do.

```
cache : {
   get : function() {
     console.log("GET!");
   },
   set : function() {
     console.log("SET!");
   }
}
```

No matter what I try, my cache functions are never called when I'm utilizing the graphQL explorer that apollo-server provides natively.

I have tried with `cacheControl : true` and with `cacheControl` set like it is in https://medium.com/brikl-engineering/serverless-graphql-cached-in-redis-with-apollo-server-2-0-f491695cac7f . Nothing.

Is there an example of how to implement basic caching in Apollo that does not utilize the paid Apollo Engine system?

Comment: do you have a Redis Server? to be able to serve chached responses you would need either `Redis Server` or `memcached server` as the package needs a host ip address on localhost or another server at `host: 'redis-server'` where redis-server is the ip-address.

Comment: Please mark an answer as an accepted one

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the implementation of this [package](http://import%20responseCachePlugin%20from%20%22apollo-server-plugin-response-cache%22;) which caches the full response to implement your own cache.

```js
import { RedisCache } from "apollo-server-redis";
import responseCachePlugin from "apollo-server-plugin-response-cache";


 const server = new ApolloServer({
    ...
    plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
     cache: new RedisCache({
        connectTimeout: 5000,
        reconnectOnError: function(err) {
          Logger.error("Reconnect on error", err);
          const targetError = "READONLY";
          if (err.message.slice(0, targetError.length) === targetError) {
            // Only reconnect when the error starts with "READONLY"
            return true;
          }
        },
        retryStrategy: function(times) {
          Logger.error("Redis Retry", times);
          if (times >= 3) {
            return undefined;
          }
          return Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
        },
        socket_keepalive: false,
        host: "localhost",
        port: 6379,
        password: "test"
      }),
 });
```

Comment: Nice this worked! For me the difference was the `plugins: [responseCachePlugin()]` part. After adding that, my custom cache methods started getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the NPM package 'apollo-server-caching' by implementing your own interface. See [Implementing Your Own Cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-caching#implementing-your-own-cache) which provides an example.